# C# overloading resolution?

Tags: c#

From the article [Anders Hejsberg interview](http://www.artima.com/intv/nonvirtualP.html), "the way we do overload resolution in C# is different from any other language"
Can somebody provide some examples with C# and Java?

Comment: I would start at [Eric Lippert's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/overload+resolution/) blog.  There are 8 posts marked taged with **overload resolution**.

Comment: Why do you need an example? In Java you can easily replace a function in a subclass, in C# you mark the function as virtual, then can override it.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: That's the correct answer to this question. If you post it as an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: @James: That is *overriding*, not *overloading*.

Comment: @james, I am talking about overloading instead of overriding.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I feel like that's kind of a half-assed answer.  There are quite a few people on SO that could answer the question in much better detail than "read X."  Content of said answers would also be more valuable to SO.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What Anders was getting at here was that the original design team explicitly designed the overload resolution algorithm to have certain properties that worked nicely with versioning scenarios, even though those properties seem backwards or confusing when you consider the scenarios without versioning.

Probably the most common example of that is the rule in C# that if any method on a more-derived class is an applicable candidate, it is automatically better than any method on a less-derived class, *even if the less-derived method has a better signature match*. This rule is not, to my knowledge, found in other languages that have overload resolution. It seems counterintuitive; if there's a method that is a better signature match, why not choose it?  The reason is because the method that is a better signature match *might have been added in a later version* and thereby be introducing a "brittle base class" failure.

For more thoughts on how various languages handle brittle base class failures, see

[Link](https://ericlippert.com/category/brittle-base-classes/)

and for more thoughts on overload resolution, see

[Link](https://ericlippert.com/category/overload-resolution/)

Comment: Do you get paged whenever your name is mentioned in a question to make sure it's answered regardless of time of day ;) ?

Comment: C++ automatically hides all functions with the same name, if one is defined in a more derived class. So unless you use a "using base::functionname" declaration (which "unhides" the name again), the effect is similar. It's not exactly the same though, because in C++ those hidden names will not be considered at all, even if no overload in the more derived class is applicable. It serves the same prupose though - new functions in base classes will not be called unintentionally.

Answer (score 1):

The way that C# handles overloading *from an internal perspective* is what's different.

The complete quote from Anders:

> I have always described myself as a
>   pragmatic guy. It's funny, because
>   versioning ended up being one of the
>   pillars of our language design. It
>   shows up in how you override virtual
>   methods in C#. Also, the way we do
>   overload resolution in C# is different
>   from any other language I know of, for
>   reasons of versioning. Whenever we
>   looked at designing a particular
>   feature, we would always cross check
>   with versioning. We would ask, "How
>   does versioning change this? How does
>   this function from a versioning
>   perspective?" It turns out that most
>   language design before has given very
>   little thought to that.

Comment: Well....that explains his [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926470/c-language-design-pillars).