# Breaking change in .NET 4.0 with method overloading and covariance

Tags: c#-4.0, covariance, overloading

after migrating from .NET 3.5 to 4.0 i have a strange problem with a function resulting in stack overflow on 4.0 while working perfectly on the 3.5 framework. I reproduced the problem with the following code:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    public Person() { }

    public Person(IPerson source)
    {
        this.Name = source.Name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonList : List<Person>
{
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<IPerson> source)
    {
        this.AddRange(source.Select(p => new Person(p)));
    }               
}
```

Provoking the error:

```
  IPerson otto = new Person { Name = "Otto" };
  IPerson fritz = new Person { Name = "Fritz" };

  PersonList list = new PersonList();

  IEnumerable<IPerson> persons = new[] { otto, fritz };
  list.AddRange(persons); //works on 3.5, stack overflow on 4.0
```

Have a look at the `AddRange(IEnumerable<IPerson> source)` method of `PersonList`.
In 3.5, the method `AddRange(IEnumerable<Person> source)` is called, derived from `List<Person>`. In 4.0 the `AddRange(IEnumerable<IPerson> source)` method is called (recursion) due to covariance, in spite the fact that a better matching function with a parameter (`IEnumerable<Person>I`) exactly matching the input parameter exists.

Is that new behaviour intended and documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is proper C# behavior because in [C# if any method on a more-derived class is an applicable candidate, it is automatically better than any method on a less-derived class, even if the less-derived method has a better signature match.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933674/c-overloading-resolution/2933724#2933724) So C# 4 has made `AddRange(IEnumerable<IPerson> source)` an applicable candidate and then the better signature `AddRange(IEnumerable<Person> source)` is in the base class so it doesn't get picked.

But it's easily fixable in your case, because of the rule.

```
public class PersonList  : List<Person>
{
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<IPerson> source)
    {
           base.AddRange(source.Select(p => new Person(p)));
    }    
}
```